# Comma-separated columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a problem: I have two tables

`Table1` which has two columns

```
Col1   Col2 
----  ------
a     value1
b     value1
b     value1
```

And `Table2`

```
Col1   Col2 
----  ------
1     a,b
2     a,c
3     a,b,c
```

I want result

```
Col1   Col2
-----  -----
a      1,2,3
b      1,3
c      2,3
```

Comment: Hm it is not possible, because you don't have field to join tables. You have to have some kind of key to join them

Comment: How is table 1 relevant to the question? It looks like all of the data in your desired result is contained within table 2

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH C AS
(
  SELECT T2.Col1,
         S.Item
  FROM Table2 AS T2
    CROSS APPLY dbo.SplitStrings(T2.Col2, ',') AS S
)
SELECT C1.Item AS Col1,
       (
       SELECT ','+CAST(C2.Col1 AS VARCHAR(10))
       FROM C AS C2
       WHERE C1.Item = C2.Item
       ORDER BY C2.Col1
       FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
       ).value('substring(text()[1], 2)', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS Col2
FROM C AS C1
GROUP BY C1.Item
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fee25/1/0)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**NOTE:** Not tested

```
select col1, [col2],
(select col1+',' from Table2 where Col2=ID
group by col1 for xml path('')) AS Col2
From Table1
```